# Storing a huge graph for shortest path calculations

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to store an unweighted, directed graph of over 5GB in a MySQL database in an efficient way for finding shortest paths. 
Currently it is stored in a single table with a column source and a comlumn targets (comma seperated), but I am getting the feeling this isn't the way to go so I am planning on converting it to a table with vertices and a table with edges.

I've got two questions:

1. What is the best way of storing the graph?
2. What shortest path algorithm should I use?

Comment: The standard algorithm is Dijkstra, which is an adapted BFS. Should you move from unweighted to weighted edges, for non-negative edges Dijkstra's algorithm remains; if negative edge weights occur, Bellman-Ford is the standard algorithm.

Comment: Ugh: have you considered using a graph DB?

Comment: Ouch, good luck with this. I would use Apache Hama, Giraph or some of the GraphDatabases like Neo4J.

Comment: use partitioning and keep segments of the graph in memory to minimize database accesses

Answer (score 2):

You should have two tables. One for nodes and one for edges. In the edges table you should have source_node_id and dest_node_id. This way you can easily make queries on the edges table to get all the outgoing nodes that are used by Dijkstra algorithm.

For a simple Dijksra algorithm explanation see this:
http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/chinneck/po/Chapter8.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Another very efficient way to store dense graphs(sparse graphs are not so efficient) is to use an adjacency matrix. Here is a link which explains it -

[Storing graphs using adjacency matrix](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/graph-representation/a/representing-graphs)

Now, to store a matrix in MySQL database you have to use the rowid as the vertex id for the rows(assuming you id your vertices as 1,2,...). The columns can just be the normal vertex names or the vertex ids again. You can keep a table which maps the vertex names to ids.

One problem you will face is the max number of columns. If your matrix is too big, you might have to split the columns into multiple tables. If you have an indexing scheme/hashing scheme to tell you immediately the name of the table from the node you want, your query should be relatively fast.

And for the shortest path, as mentioned by others,  Dijkstra algorithm is the best shortest path finding algorithm out there.